# Stack overflow with Big Integer

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger

I'm dealing with A LOT of BigIntegers along with recursion, which is causing stack overflow. Is there any way for me to get around this or is there something I'm doing wrong that's causing this stack overflow?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class Recur {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    BigInteger n, m;

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        n = new BigInteger((80 - 70) + 70, r);
        int num1 = n.intValue();
        m = new BigInteger((80 - 70) + 70, r);
        int num2 = m.intValue();


        System.out.println("N: " + n + " " + "M: " + m);
        System.out.println("Recursive GCD: " + recursiveGCD(num1, num2));           
        System.out.println("Iterative GCD: " + iterativeGCD(num1, num2));
    }

}

public static int recursiveGCD(int n, int m) {
    if (n == 0)
        return m;
    else if (m == 0)
        return n;
    else if (n > m)
        return recursiveGCD(n % m, m);
    else if (m < n)
        return recursiveGCD(n, m % n);
    else 
        return n;

}

public static int iterativeGCD(int n, int m) {
    while (n != 0 && m != 0) {
        if (n > m)
            n = n % m ;
        else if (m > n)
            m = m % n;
        else
            return n;
    }

    if (n == 0)
        return m;
    else
        return n;


    }

}
```

Comment: Where to start?  (and this looks like homework... so I'm going to give you some things to think about).  (a) that first parameter in each use of the BigInteger constructor can be simplified... keep the noise to a minimum so we can all focus on what you're trying to do.  (b) You're converting a value possibly as large as 2^80 (and I'm thinking you're hoping for something in excess of 2^70) into a Java _int_ - a 32 bit (2^32) value.  Note also that a Java _long_ is still only 2^64, and that both _int_ and _long_ are unsigned.  You've got some things to work out there.

Comment: @Richard Sitze Yeah, in the BigInteger constructor, I thought it was possible to set a specified range but later learned I couldn't. I'm also converting the BigInteger to an int because the assignment specifically asks for the functions to accept ints, which is honestly making this harder for me... But nonetheless, thank you for your help.

Comment: `n = new BigInteger((80 - 70) + 70, r);  int num1 = n.intValue();` generates a random number between 0 and 2^80-1 and then discards the high-order 48 bits, resulting in a value between -2^31 and 2^31-1.  Are you sure that's what you wanted to do? Why bother generating an 80-bit random and then truncate it?

Comment: @JimGarrison I actually wonder that too. My professor's the one who asked for the functions to only accept integers....I feel it defeats the purpose of using BigIntegers.

Comment: If you want to figure out your stack overflow exception, I highly recommend you step through the code one line at a time in your IDE debugger.

Comment: @JimGarisson I would if I weren't in a time crunch right now.

Comment: That.... makes no sense.  I ran your code and figured out the problem within a few seconds... it's obvious in the debugger. Do it.

Comment: Either use a debugger, or log (print) your intermediate values.  If you're in a time-crunch, you don't have time to argue :-)   Print the params to your recursive method immediately on entry to the method.

Comment: Take a closer look at the javadoc for _BigInteger.intValue_.

Comment: @JimGarrison my problem is that I'm hardly familiar with the debugger.

Comment: Now is the time to learn.  You can probably learn enough in 1 hour of studying to figure out your problem. Or you can insert print statements in your code as suggested by @RichardSitze above.

Comment: @RichardSitze I have other questions to get to on my assignment that I have to do within the hour, so I'll try the print statement method. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You are Getting Stack Overflow because your stack in your OS is designed to store a limited amount of memory addresses for each running program.

Also maybe BigInt has a particular influence but i think that you can get rid of that error just by making a linear program.

Comment: No, there's a very real bug in the implementation that causes the stack overflow.